# Android ListView Item Optical Feedback

Tags: android, listview, onclick, feedback

I have to make a listview that give optical feedback when clicked. 
The Listitem is the following xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="@color/white"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/test_grey" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:textColor="@color/FirstLevelText"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

ListViewis handled by an adapter...The problem is that i should also change the icon in the ImageView and the color of the text in the TextView, also the background of the RelativeLayout should be changed from black to white (when pressed) and from white to black (when status "pressed" is over). How to do that programmatically ? I know that the "normal" way for changing background is using the xml-selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/list_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

But how to handle that with the TextView and the imageView ?